# alert button for drag and drop table rows without saving not appearing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, onbeforeunload

I have a table which I have made sortable(rows can be dragged and dropped using jquery) , I want that if the user drags and drops the rows and forgets to click on update button and tries to navigate to other page then an alert should appear to ask 'if you want to save before leaving'.

Below is my code , to make it sortable.

```
   $(function () {
        $("#tbllookup1 tbody").sortable({
            items: 'tr',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            droponempty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addclass("selected");
                
            },

            stop: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.removeclass("selected");

            },
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
            }
        });
    });
```

As suggested by someone on stackoverflow , I tried setting up a flag and using beforeunload ,but not sure why the alert is not showing.

Below is the modified code...

```
 $(function () {
        // set the flag on drop
        let $tbody = $("#tblLookup1 tbody").sortable({
            // ... settings
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                $tbody.data('is-dirty', true).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
            }
        });
        
        // remove the flag when submitting the form through the update button
        $('#tblLookup1').on('submit', () => $tbody.data('is-dirty', false));

        // check the flag when the user leaves the page and display 
        // a message if it's set
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
            if ($tbody.data('is-dirty')) {
                return 'Do you want to save the data before leaving?';
            }
        });
        alert(is - dirty);
    });
```

I also tried another thing

```
var formSubmitting = false;
    var setFormSubmitting = function () { formSubmitting = true; };

    window.onload = function () {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
            if (formSubmitting) {
                return undefined;
            }

            var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

            (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; 
            return confirmationMessage; 
        });
```

This does display an alert but the alert message is by default one and not what I am providing, also this alert is not binded with my drag and drop of rows but appears everytime I try to navigate to a different link.

My button

```
                  <input type="submit" class="btn CreateButtonColor" id="btnSave" value="Update" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

what shall I do in either of the two to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. None of the JavaScript code looks correct. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tbllookup1 tbody").sortable({
    items: '> tr',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    axis: 'y',
    droponempty: false,
    start: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      $(this).data("saved", false);
    },
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).append(ui.item);
    }
  });

  $("#tbllookup1-save-btn").click(function() {
    // Save new Order to DB
    $("#tbllookup1 tbody").data("saved", true);
  })

  $(window).on("beforeunload", function(event) {
    // Custom messages are gerneally not supported by modern browsers.
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#tbllookup1 tbody").data("saved") == false) {
      return event.returnValue = "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to navigate away?";
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="tbllookup1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-saved="true">
    <tr>
      <td>1001</td>
      <td>Homer Simpson</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1020</td>
      <td>Marge Simpson</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1031</td>
      <td>Bart Simpson</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1089</td>
      <td>Lisa Simpson</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>Maggie Simpson</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="tbllookup1-save-btn">Save Changes</button>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Trigger unload</a>
```

There are things to look at here. Please see the `items` page:

https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

> **Type:** Selector, **Default:** `"> *"`, Specifies which items inside the element should be sortable.

The calls are `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. If the function name is not correct, they will throw an error.

You can call `beforeunload` yet modern browsers do not allow for custom text as a security precaution. The User will still get a notification and the option to stay.

Using the `data` attribute is a great way to store the state. When the page loads, we assume the details are saved, `true`. When a change is made, we can change saved to `false`. If the User does save, we can change the state back to `true`.